# Elasticsearch indices: Document mapping type name can't start with '_', found: [_doc]"}]

Tags: laravel, elasticsearch

When I try to index my elasticsearch in laravel by:

```
php artisan elastic:index
```

I get following error:

```
   start with '_', found: [_doc]
at org.elasticsearch.cluster.metadata.MetaDataMappingService$PutMappingExecutor.applyRequest(MetaDataMappingService.java:297) ~[elasticsearch-6.0.0.jar:6.0.0]
at org.elasticsearch.cluster.metadata.MetaDataMappingService$PutMappingExecutor.execute(MetaDataMappingService.java:230) ~[elasticsearch-6.0.0.jar:6.0.0]
at org.elasticsearch.cluster.service.MasterService.executeTasks(MasterService.java:640) ~[elasticsearch-6.0.0.jar:6.0.0]
at org.elasticsearch.cluster.service.MasterService.calculateTaskOutputs(MasterService.java:270) ~[elasticsearch-6.0.0.jar:6.0.0]
at org.elasticsearch.cluster.service.MasterService.runTasks(MasterService.java:195) [elasticsearch-6.0.0.jar:6.0.0]
at org.elasticsearch.cluster.service.MasterService$Batcher.run(MasterService.java:130) [elasticsearch-6.0.0.jar:6.0.0]
at org.elasticsearch.cluster.service.TaskBatcher.runIfNotProcessed(TaskBatcher.java:150) [elasticsearch-6.0.0.jar:6.0.0]
at org.elasticsearch.cluster.service.TaskBatcher$BatchedTask.run(TaskBatcher.java:188) [elasticsearch-6.0.0.jar:6.0.0]
at org.elasticsearch.common.util.concurrent.ThreadContext$ContextPreservingRunnable.run(ThreadContext.java:569) [elasticsearch-6.0.0.jar:6.0.0]
at org.elasticsearch.common.util.concurrent.PrioritizedEsThreadPoolExecutor$TieBreakingPrioritizedRunnable.runAndClean(PrioritizedEsThreadPoolExecutor.java:247) [elasticsearch-6.0.0.jar:6.0.0]
at org.elasticsearch.common.util.concurrent.PrioritizedEsThreadPoolExecutor$TieBreakingPrioritizedRunnable.run(PrioritizedEsThreadPoolExecutor.java:210) [elasticsearch-6.0.0.jar:6.0.0]
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128) [?:?]
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628) [?:?]
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834) [?:?]
```

I saw this a lot on the internet, but never a clear explanation.. How can I solve this?

I'm using Elasticsearch6.0.0

Answer (score 0):

You simply need to upgrade to ES 6.x. Prior to that version it was not allowed to create a mapping type with an underscore as the first character, except than the `_default_` one.

Comment: Then you need to downgrade to a Laravel version that's compatible with ES 5.5

Comment: No other solutions? I just need to import data into the indices (best via sql)

Comment: when I update to ES6 I get following error (see question)